# jquery mistake at response or where for autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, xml, autocomplete

**Background info first: App is an old .net framework 1.1 app (json was not supported back then so I had to use xml.**  I cannot upgrade this specific app for reasons not worth going into.

---

I am trying to add autocomplete to a textbox on my site.  But the autocomplete should pop up after certain words are typed.  For instance, in a textbox if I start typing the autocomplete would pop up.  Once I hit the space key and start typing again then autocomplete will come up again.

I found something cool, the jquery docs included something exactly like this found here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple I've done pretty much what they are doing but my autocomplete does not come up.  Here is my jquery code:

### My jquery code

```
function split(val) 
{
  return val.split(/\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) 
{
  return split(term).pop();
}

$("#txtTags").bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        //parameters for the ajax call.
        var FacilityID = $("#ddlFacility").val();
        var ClientID = $("#ddlClient").val();   
        var params = '{"ClientID":"' + ClientID + '", "FacilityID":"' + FacilityID + '"}';

    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item.
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }).
autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: params,
                url: "GetTags.asmx/GetTags",
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(xml) {
                var data = [];
                 $(xml).find('string').each(function(){ 
                    data.push($(this).text());
                    });
                //response(data);
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        data, extractLast(request.term)));
          },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        }, 
        search: function() {
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast( this.value );
          if(typeof(term) !== 'undefined')
            {           
            if (term.length < 1) {
                return false;
            }
          }
        }, 
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
    });
```

I've commented as best as I can so if you have questions please let me know.  I know the .asmx web service file is returning the correct data as my output running the webservice from ie / chrome is as follows:

### Result of XML

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/quikfix.jakah.com/GetTags">
<string>3g</string>
<string>6283</string>
<string>7641</string>
<string>8-id</string>
<string>80070005</string>
<string>active-directory</string>
<string>ad</string>
<string>addin</string>
<string>authentication</string>
<string>badge</string>
<string>batch</string>
<string>boot</string>
</ArrayOfStrings>
```

Whatever I type into the textbox I am not seeing any errors in chrome developer tools / ie tools.  I just dont get the autocomplete coming up.  Is there anything noticably wrong in my jquery?

---

### Web Service (.asmx)

Additional info here is my web service if anyone is interested, its just vb.net:

```
Public Function GetTags(ByVal ClientID As Long, ByVal FacilityID As Long) As String()
        Dim arr() As String = BindTags(ClientID, FacilityID)
        Return arr
    End Function
    Public Function BindTags(ByVal ClientID As Long, ByVal FacilityID As Long) As String()
        Dim cmdSelect As SqlCommand
        Dim conMyData As SqlConnection
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim myList As New ArrayList

        'try and make a connection   
        Try
            conMyData = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("strConn"))
            cmdSelect = New SqlCommand("select_tags_grid", conMyData)

            With cmdSelect
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                'add parameters
                .Parameters.Add("@ClientID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = ClientID
                .Parameters.Add("@FacilityID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = FacilityID
                .Parameters.Add("@SortOrder", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = 4
                'check the clientid
                conMyData.Open()
                reader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            End With

            While (reader.Read())
                myList.Add(CType(reader("Tag"), String))
            End While

            Dim arr() As String = CType(myList.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String")), String())
            Return arr
        Catch e As Exception
            'clean up and close resources
            Throw e
        Finally
            cmdSelect = Nothing
            conMyData.Close()
            conMyData = Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

---

## Findings so far

I am very close here, what I see is if I remove the parameters from my jquery and my web service, namely:

```
  //parameters for the ajax call.
        //var FacilityID = $("#ddlFacility").val();
        //var ClientID = $("#ddlClient").val(); 
        //var params = '{"ClientID":"' + ClientID + '", "FacilityID":"' + FacilityID + '"}';
```

The autocomplete shows up correctly.  However I need these parameters...so when I do add them back into both my jquery and my web service (my asmx file) then chrome throws an internal server 500 error.  It says:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/xml; charset=utf-8. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke() at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

But I need the text/xml type because json was not supported in .net 1.1.  Please anyone?

Comment: Is the js code inside `$(function() { ...`?

Comment: yes of course, its in document.ready()

Comment: I also posted the two functions `split()`, and `extractLast()` which I originally forgot to post in the jquery section...sorry.

Comment: Am I filtering correctly?  `response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
      data, extractLast(request.term)));` ?  Meaning when I type in a 'c' it should show me things that begin with 'c', so maybe my filter is incorrect?

Comment: The filtering is similar to the one on the example page, so it should work. Maybe it's in the result xml parsing. I would check there with a debugger.

Comment: How can I check the result of the xml in the debugger, sorry my experience is very small in jquery and front end development.

Comment: Open Chrome dev tools -> Network tab, click on XHR. Trigger the autocomplete and you should see the list populating. You can see the response under the `Response` tab.

Comment: @CodrinEugeniu-As soon as I get rid of the parameters the autocomplete shows up.  I need those parameters.  I can alert them and they are passing the correct values.  As soon as I add them back in, in chrome developer tools I get a 500 internal server error telling me that: `System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is invalid: text/xml; charset=utf-8.   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()`

Comment: Is it easier if we move this to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28112/discussion-between-codrin-eugeniu-and-ojm86o)

Comment: @CodrinEugeniu I went to the chat but you are not responding...

Comment: I got it thank goodness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

```
function split(val) 
    {
      //return val.split(/\s*/);
      return val.split(" ");
    }

    function extractLast(term) 
    {
      return split(term).pop();
    }

        //parameters for the ajax call.
        var FacilityID = $("#ddlFacility").val();
        var ClientID = $("#ddlClient").val();   
        var params = '{"ClientID":"' + ClientID + '", "FacilityID":"' + FacilityID + '"}';

$("#txtTags").bind( "keydown", function( event ) {  
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item.
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).data( "ui-autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }).
    autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: "ClientID=" + ClientID + "&FacilityID=" + FacilityID,
                url: "GetTags.asmx/GetTags",
                dataType: "xml",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(xml) {
                var data = [];
                 $(xml).find('string').each(function(){ 
                    data.push($(this).text());
                    });
                //response(data);
                // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        data, extractLast(request.term)));
          },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        }, 
        search: function() {
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast( this.value );
          if(typeof(term) !== 'undefined')
            {           
            if (term.length < 1) {
                return false;
            }
          }
        }, 
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) 
        {       
            var terms = split(this.value);          
            // remove the current input          
            terms.pop();          
            // add the selected item          
            terms.push(ui.item.value);          
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end          
            terms.push("");          
            //add space to each term object
            this.value = terms.join(" ");          
            return false;        
        },
    });
```